# Cannot test RSpec due to namespace clash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, namespaces, nameerror

I have a `User` model in my Rails application and I have a `UserQueue` model as well.

`User has_many UserQueues` and `UserQueue belongs_to User`.

Here is the problem. When I try to test UserQueue and try to create one with

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { @queue = user.user_queues.create(queue_privacy_id: 1) }
```

I get the following error.

```
NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::user_queue
```

What I understand from this is RSpec expects the UserQueue to be in the namespace of User(ie User::UserQueue). However that is not the case in my app. And I can't name the model Queue since it is reserved.

Is there a way to tell RSpec that the model has no namespace?

Here are my models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected

  has_many :user_queues, :class_name => "user_queue", :foreign_key => "user_id"

  def name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
end


class UserQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :queue_privacy_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

Comment: Post your User and UserQueue models

Comment: try `:class_name => "UserQueue"`

Comment: @zetetic where? in the before block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the rep to comment, but was going to ask you to post your factories as well.

**Some other ideas:**
Take a look at how you can handle [assocations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) with FactoryGirl.  I'm assuming you are not on Rails 4 because of:

`attr_accessible :queue_privacy_id, :user_id`

Comment: yes this is a rails 3 app. but the associations section you linked me to solved it. thanks